# php preg_replace reuse of subject

Tags: php, hyperlink, preg-replace, reusability

I've got a big problem and hopefully you can help me out...

I'd like to code a plugin. The plugin should search on a website (for example `www.example.com/index.php` for a specific word for example `Number1`. Afterwords the word found should be replaced by an hyperlink. The link should guide to an extern website for example `www.example2.com/index.php`.

According to the current website, the found word should added to the hyperlink. So if the current site is `www.example.com/index.php` and the found word is `Number1`, the hyperlink should look like this:

```
www.example2.com/index.php/Number1
```

And it shouldn't be always the same hyperlink, but created dynamic by the word this plugin finds.

Beneath is my current code. 
I hope someone can help me out. Thanks.

```
public function onContentPrepare($context, &$row, &$params, $page = 0)
{
    $text = $row->text;    

    $pattern = array();
    $pattern[0] = '/Number1/';
    $pattern[1] = '/Number2/';
    $pattern[2] = '/Number3/';

    $Subject = array();
    $Subject[2] = 'https://www.example.com/index.php/';
    $Subject[1] = '(...)';
    $Subject[0] = '(...)';

    $row->text = preg_replace($pattern,$subject,$text);
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look into [preg_replace_callback](http://php.net/preg_replace_callback) so that you have one pattern, and then you generate the links via a callback.

Comment: thx I'll try tomorrow